# Schedule Agent - Schedule's Based on a Profile Document Fields

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there a way to make a schedule agent that runs on the specific dates and information that the user entered in a profile document?

Two Scenarios:

A:
The field being used from the profile document has the properties "Can have multiple values" activated. I would like the agent to run whatever the values are inside that field. The field contains the specific dates.

B: There are multiple fields like "Schedule: "Daily" or "Once a month" and the likes" which is almost the same as when you create the schedule for the agent that would be used by the agent as the properties for scheduling and running the agent.

This is possible by always running a scheduled agent and checking the data from the profile document then just check if the agent should continue or not but is there another way which would be better than the one mentioned earlier since it required the agent to always run most of the time. I would like to create the setup of the agent based on profile document.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't see the problem in running the agent every 5 minutes and checking the profile document. That does not cause any practical load on the server.

Comment: I think it's a waste of resources to run an agent every 5 minutes if you want to execute code "Once a month" especially if server hosts hundreds of applications. But yes, it depends on size of company, number of applications, system infrastructure and so on.

Comment: Actually if I understand the question correctly, it's enough to run the agent once a day. But I like your answer, it's much better than the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks. Without setting schedule per LotusScript you actually have to run agent every 5 minutes because user can set in profile "Daily at xx:xx" and xx:xx might be already some minutes later and user expects running the code at xx:xx the current day and not the next day.

Comment: Hi panu, well the user would change the value any time in the day so it must be run depending on the details on the document thus I can't set a time in the setting since the user must be able to change it through the document.. but I requested to the user that it would just run one time daily and just check the details on the document. They agreed thankfully.. But Knut answer is really helpful and it added new knowledge to me... Thanks a lot Panu and Knut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such functionality supported in Lotus Notes. Agent scheduling setup cannot be directly based on a profile document.

I would implement an agent that runs every 5 minutes (interval depends on the agent's goal) and check settings in a profile document and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi Rafael,, I see,, that's what I think too.. but I was really hoping that there would be a better way. Since if we are going to think about it it's really not a good solution.. Okay then I'll just go with that idea,, Thanks a lot Rafael. If ever you found a way like that then please do share it too me.. Thanks a lot Rafael.. haha

Comment: probably won't work as expected. Profile documents are cached, so not reliable to read if you expect the value to change. Also read this TN on implications of running agents outside of AMGR scheduler. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21279832

Comment: Profile documents have drawbacks. And from my point of view the best way is avoid use of these documents. And use common documents for settings. If you use profile documents for settings, note that profile documents do not participate in replication process. And if you have several replicas, then your settings won't be replicated if  profile docs were used to store settings.

Comment: Profile documents are definitely supposed to replicate. There have been occasional bugs that did affect this, but as far as I know IBM has addressed them.  If you have a problem with profile document replication in your environment, you should open an incident with IBM support. The primary drawback is what Simon said: they are cached in memory, so changes that have been made in the NSF (e.g., by replication!) may not be immediately visible to all processes that read them.

Comment: I met many hard-to-catch bugs related to replication of profile documents. Maybe they should be replicated, but this mechanism does not work properly. And I do not recommend to rely on this mechanism. We spent a lot of time and money to rewrite big parts of our applications, related to profile documents and settings, because of the replication problem. From my point of view and my experience use of common documents instead of profile documents is more reliable.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the information know I know more about the profile document.. I think I also tried replicating my database and it also replicated the profile document.. But thanks a lot for the information that also helped me a lot.. So it is better to use documents rather than profile document for the settings? Okay Noted.. Thanks

Comment: Yes, from my point of view it is better to use common documents to store settings.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set an agent's schedule with LotusScript. Here is the code (12 years old but still working):

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/0/65389424caefa06980256b260051da56?OpenDocument

With Sub `GetAssistInfo` you get the current schedule values of an agent. You can change them and save the new values with Sub `SetAssistInfo`.

Example: set agent's schedule to daily at 02:00:

```vb
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim info As AssistInfo
Dim agentName As String

agentName = "yourAgent"
GetAssistInfo session.CurrentDatabase, agentName, info  
info.IntervalType = 2   ' set "Daily"
info.Time1 = 360000 * 2 ' set 02:00
SetAssistInfo session.CurrentDatabase, agentName, info
```

You have to figure out the possible values for schedule's parameter. The code behind the link offers a message box which shows the current values of an agent. So, it's easy to find the values you have to set.

Having this, you can run the code from your profile document and set agent's schedule. You could also let your agent itself change it's own schedule for next run.

Comment: Hi Knut, thanks a lot for the information.. It just happened that the answer I selected was the first one to answer.. and I also resolved the issue by requesting to the user that the agent would just run once at a specific time and just check the profile document.. Thanks a lot Knut, this code would probably help me a lot in the future thus I will store this info and link. This is the first time I encountered a code that would change it's schedule and it is really going to be helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: The problem with the GetAssistInfo code is that it only works on Windows - and only on 32-bit Domino (at least according to my experience in using ths on 64-bit Domino).